# Security Scan Warning: "External Service Interaction via HTTP Header Injection after a DNS lookup request"

Tags: security, nginx, owasp

The security scan of our Java application gave the following warning:

**Review application endpoints to ensure input validation is performed on all input that may influence external service calls/connections**

*The WAS External Sensor has detected a External Service Interaction via HTTP Header Injection after a DNS lookup request of type A for domain ...*

> Validate **user inputs in all headers including Host header** and
> **X-Forwarded-Host header. The header value should be processed only if**
> **it appears on a approved/safe list of FQDNs.**  For more information see
> the OWASP SSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet.

Do I need to add a Filter of some kind to check the incoming Host/X-Forwarded-Host header value? Any idea what needs to be done for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using this header in your application/infrastructure to route requests to a specific host(s), one option is to just delete this header.